# ruby - Pass a function that expects a function param to a function

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

```
def do_whatever # func A receives func B
    params = { test: 1 }
    proc = Proc.new{ puts "an important exec #{params[:test]}"; return "important response" } # func C
    yield(proc)
end

do_whatever do
    begin # func B
        resp = yield # executes func C
        puts resp
    rescue => e
        puts e
    end
end
```

Hi, I want a function (e.g. func A) to be passed a block of function (e.g. func B) and executes it. That block of function (e.g. function B) also receives a block of function (e.g. func C) that is initialized in that function. On above code, I expect to see the output:

```
an important exec 1
important response
```

but instead I got an error: no block given (yield)

Comment: You use "function" to refer to methods, procs, and blocks. The question would probably be easier to understand if you use the proper terms instead of the umbrella term "function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def do_whatever # func A receives func B
  params = { test: 1 }
  proc = Proc.new{ puts "an important exec #{params[:test]}"; next "important response" } # func C
  yield(proc)
end

do_whatever do |func_c|
  begin # func B
      resp = func_c.call
      puts resp
  rescue => e
      puts e
  end
end
```

When you call yield inside `do_whatever` that is passed as the argument to the block of `do_whatever`, and returns the proc as an argument to block. Since return does not work in Procs, you will need to use `next` instead.

Comment: Technically speaking `return` will work perfectly fine in this context because you can return inside a method body; however this will be the return value for `do_whatever` and `puts resp` would not be reached. Additionally `next` is unnecessary because there is no loop. Due to the fact that ruby implicitly returns the last statement you can remove the `next` keyword and the functionality will remain the same.  The real issue was the `yield` inside `do_whatever` because this `yield` had no block to yield to an you fixed this with the explicit `func_c.call`